# Change image in static page header when change content the jquery page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a site in jquery and in header a static image, that I want to change when I click to change content in the jquery.

site: http://swapes.com/intech2

how could I do this? (I have no example code because I do not know how to begin)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle is very simple:

```
$("#img_id_here").click(function(){
    //do modifications here
})
```

EDIT:
if you want to edit the image source, as the example above, but when the image is clicked (as specified) you can do:

```
$("#img_id_here").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'new_source_for_image');
})
```

The above should be added to your javascript file.
As an alternative, you can just add the following to your HTML (or PHP) file:

```
<script>$("#img_id_here").click(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'new_source_for_image');})</script>
```

Comment: I'am new in php.. do not understand how :(

Comment: @user2627743 That is actually JQuery, not PHP. I edited the post so you can have an example

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `<img>` tag, and you give it an ID:

```
<img id='headerImage' src='...' />
```

In jquery you can do this:

```
$("#headerImage").attr('src', 'new.img.src');
```

Comment: here src='...' (add in all pages were change the image?

Comment: Well I'm not exactly sure what image you are talking about.  Or what you mean by that comment.  There is another way to get an image on the page - via css - `background-image`.  If that's how you're loading your image, you can change it in jquery using `$('#headerImage').css({'background-image': "url('image.png')"});`

Comment: Need add on the button the onclick?

Comment: add me on yahoo messenger for help me, i will pay you... my id: amor3tuo  , thank you!